# How can I present a series of chessboards in one column, with text in another column?

Tags: two-column, chess, chessboard

I would like to create a document where each move in a game of chess is annotated.

I envisage having a chessboard on the left hand side, with annotations on the right.

Sorry about not including a small example. I am new to Tex.

Comment: I'm not all too familiar, but there a fair few packages on CTAN specially for drawing chessboards in LaTeX. Try `skak` or any other packages from [here](https://www.ctan.org/topic/font-chess).

Comment: @Troy A better link is https://www.ctan.org/topic/games, it doesn't show only fonts, but also package like xskak, texmate and chessboard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}


\usepackage{skak}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}


\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{cc}
\begin{minipage}{0.45\textwidth}
\newgame
\showboard  
\end{minipage}
&
\begin{minipage}{0.45\textwidth}
Black can win in two moves, with white's assistance.

\lipsum[1-2]
\end{minipage}
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Could you extend it to another board so I can make sure I can reproduce it please? (I'm guessing for each board-text pairing, you need a new pair of minipages?)

Comment: Actually, there's a rather important bug in this solution which doesn't show up in the example! The general structure should be `\begin{minipage}` [draw board] `\end{minipage} & \begin{minipage}` [comments] `\end{minipage} \\ \begin{minipage}` [draw board] ... etc ... `\end{minipage} \end{tabular}`. Note the `&` (missing in @JPi's example) and the two backslash characters  between the rows of the table .

Comment: There's only one row here... but yes, one can extend it.

Answer (score 4):

I think a `longtable` could be more suitable.

I've also created a new column type `K` to avoid typing the `minipage` environment at every cell.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{skak}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\newcolumntype{K}{>{\begin{minipage}[t][\height][c]{0.45\textwidth}\arraybackslash}c<{\end{minipage}}}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}{KK}
\newgame
\showboard  
&
A short description
\\
\newgame
\showboard  
&
Black can win in two moves, with white's assistance.
\\
\newgame
\showboard  
&
Black can win in two moves, with white's assistance.
\\
\newgame
\showboard  
&
A medium description \lipsum[1]
\\
\newgame
\showboard  
&
Black can win in two moves, with white's assistance.
\lipsum[1]
\\
\newgame
\showboard  
&
A long description \lipsum[1-2]
\\
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Why is it necessary to place the contents in a `minipage` rather than simply use a `p{0.45\textwidth}p{0.45\textwidth}`?  I see that that aligns the text on the right to the bottom of the cell but I understand that not to be the expected behaviour of the `p` column type.

Comment: @DaiBowen I did some tests and if I remember well with only `p` the alignment wasn't perfect, the text was a bit higher than the chessboards. I'm not at home now, I'll re-try tonight and I'll let you know.

Comment: @DaiBowen I confirm: with only `p{0.45\textwidth}p{0.45\textwidth}` the text is positioned a bit higher w.r.t. the chessboards...

Comment: I agree something goes wrong (I think actually the text is typeset starting from the bottom of the chessboard and goes below rather than the text is too high - if you look at the rows using `\lipsum`), I'm simply curious as to why - it's not the vertical alignment I expect from a `p`-column, I suppose the internals of `\showboard` do something.

Comment: @DaiBowen You're right, it's at the bottom, I didn't look at the first row! I don't know the reason, I'm a beginner :):):):)